# U.S. Bonds Taxed Interest and Current Value

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, bonds, interest

Series EE Bond just matured and I cashed it in.

The current value that I received in cash was only a little more than the original face value.

However, the interest I am paying taxes on is half the amount of the original face value.

Why don't I see that amount when I cashed it in and why do I have to pay taxes on that amount?

Thank You.

Comment: Is it a paper bond or an electronic bond?

Comment: @littleadv: paper. I think I figured it out, it was purchased for me when i was a kid, and I believe you purchase bonds for half of the face value....is that right? I have never used bonds before (never mind actual cash these days) so I am a complete idiot when it comes to this. Found this tool: http://www.savings-bond-advisor.com/savings-bond-calculator/#calc

Comment: Exactly. Paper bonds were purchased at 50% discount, which is exactly the interest you're now paying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got paper bonds. Paper bonds were purchased at 50% discount, which is exactly the interest you're now taxed on.

More information on EE and other bonds can be found at [Treasury Direct web site](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eetaxconsider.htm).